# Twitter bootstrap select picker add "Choose One"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i'm using [Bootstrap select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), and i'm trying to add default option like **Choose One**

Here's my html code,

```
<div class="container">

  <h3>Bootstrap Select</h3>
  <select id="dataCombo" class="selectpicker">
    <option data-hidden="true">Choose One</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
    <option value="six">Six</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Also i'm using [jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org) plugin for validation. On form submit above select option is not validating and i'm getting **choose one** if i **print_r all posted data**

Did anyone know where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: you should possibly add a custom validation for *Choose One*, to prevent form submit.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Bootstrap Select</h3>
    <select id="dataCombo" class="selectpicker">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose One</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
        <option value="four">Four</option>
        <option value="five">Five</option>
        <option value="six">Six</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Is this what you have wanted ...